# Index Match formula in a table, works for 1st row but not the rest

Tags: excel-2016

I'm placing an `Index-Match` formula inside a table, while the reference is another table in another sheet.
The formula should give me the value from my reference table, after searching for a match in 3 columns:

```
=INDEX(Master[Individual Preventive Stroke], MATCH([@Line],Master[Line],0),MATCH([@Process],Master[Process],0),MATCH([@Machine],Master[Equipment],0))

'Master is the reference table name.
```

When testing, the correct value shows for the 1st row, and auto corrects when I change the value in my reference table. But when I copy the same formula to the 2nd row and beyond, I get an invalid cell reference error `#REF!`. What went wrong, is it because I used a table?

[image: Master table]

[image: result]